# Configuring Gradle project to depend on lwjgl

Tags: java, gradle, lwjgl

How do I configure `build.gradle` to depend on LWJGL?

I'm new to Gradle, and how to configure library dependencies is clear as mud to me.

It's my understanding is that one can specify library dependencies for Gradle to download rather than checking them in to source control, but any sort of help with configuring things would be appreciated.

(I don't know any Ivy or Maven.)

Answer (score 4, accepted):

I think what you want is to have lwjgl in your build classpath and resolve it automatically right?

try this snippet:

```
plugins {
    id "java"
}

repositories{
    maven {
        url = "http://adterrasperaspera.com/lwjgl" 
    }
}

dependencies{
    implementation "org.lwjgl:lwjgl:2.6"
    implementation "org.lwjgl:lwjgl-util:2.6"
}
```

This snippet above defines a maven repository which contains the lwjgl libs and defines two compile dependencies to your project.

regards,
René

Comment: Awesome! Thank you. For bonus points, I still don't know how to run it. Do you know how to set up the class path to specify those jars that are downloaded? Strangely, I can't find them.

Comment: http://www.gradle.org/application_plugin.html should do the trick, if your method of "run it" means "execute a main method."